# Moving images using accelerometer 360 degrees

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, 360-degrees

I have 2d photos of a object , i want to create a 360 spin effect. I have already implemented this using ontouch. But i want to move images left or right based on the sensor .

Comment: You can translate your view based on sensor data with respective coordinates for example +x should move the view to right and vice versa.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, i have used roll value to move the image, but the effect is not smooth. I want to implement effect like fyuse 3d app , image changes on rolling device either to left or right .

Comment: For smoothness you can use `TranslateAnimation`.

Comment: Still not able to implement sensor feature any help ?

Comment: Please post the code. what did you try?